# Unable to find the Placeholder menu

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, xcode7

I am unable to find the Placeholder menu. Attaching my screenshot.
Is there any way to easily add constraints. It took me more than 2 hours just to resolve the constraints.? And the pic seems to be differently oriented in different simulators even after using the Editor> Size to Fit Option.
[image]
Would highly appreciate the help.
Thanks.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Constraint scan easily be added by ctrl-dragging between elements or by using he buttons in the bottom border of the window, but the exception you have shown probably means you have linked the textfield to the IBOutlet

Comment: *not* linked...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to add constraints is by using "Pin" (second from the right in the attached image), which is located at the very bottom of the interface builder. [image]

If you're having some trouble understanding AutoLayout, I recommend reading Apple's documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/

Let me know if you need further clarification.